# TyphoonConfig is trying to load plist with wrong bundle path

Tags: ios, swift, typhoon

I'm new to Typhoon and can't seem to figure out how to get my Configuration.plist to load correctly. My project is modeled after the Swift PocketForecast example, although I started with my own CocoaPods based project and added Typhoon to it myself (i.e. I didn't start from a cloned PocketForecast project). I am using plist integration with multiple assemblies.

When I use this:

```
public dynamic func config() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.configDefinitionWithName("Configuration.plist")
}
```

I get a file not found error and in the debugger I can see the path its using is "/path/to/MyProject.app/Frameworks/Typhoon.framework", but of course my config file isn't located there, it's located at "/path/to/MyProject.app/Configuration.plist". Yes, I have confirmed the file is actually there.

I tried to fix this problem by doing something like this:

```
public dynamic func config() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(TyphoonConfigPostProcessor.self) {
        (definition) in
        definition.injectMethod("useResourceAtPath:") {
            (method) in
            method.injectParameterWith(self.configURL())
        }
    }
}

public dynamic func configURL() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withFactory(self.configBundle(), selector: "URLForResource:withExtension:", parameters: {
        (initializer) in
        initializer.injectParameterWith("Configuration")
        initializer.injectParameterWith("plist")
    })
}

public dynamic func configBundle() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(NSBundle.self) {
        (definition) in
        definition.useInitializer("mainBundle")
    }
}
```

And strangely, this works – sometimes. It appears random, and based on the order that my other Typhoon assemblies are loaded. In other words, sometimes everything works great, but other times the Typhoon initialization bombs out with a variety of different errors like "No component matching id XYZ" or "can't find value in config". But like I said, sometimes it works just fine.

I must be missing some fundamental piece of how Typhoon is initializing, so any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** So after some poking around it looks like the first method I tried above is failing because of a problem with CocoaPods using a framework instead of a static lib for Swift projects? I found this code in TyphoonResource:

```
+ (id <TyphoonResource>)withName:(NSString *)name
{
    return [self withName:name inBundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
}
```

And since `[self class]` will resolve to a class within the Typhoon framework, I guess I see why that is the bundle it is the bundle it is using, but it seems like a bug to me. I'm going to see if I can figure out why this doesn't break the PocketForecast app.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you've found a bug. I think we're using `[self class]` there because it used to help with old 'logic' style tests . . . it would be (AFAIK) safe to change this to `[NSBundle mainBundle]`. Let's try this. I'll push to main branch and you can `pod 'Typhoon', :head`

Comment: https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/issues/329

Comment: Replacing with `[NSBundle mainBundle]` worked for me. Did it break other things?

Comment: it did not, but I changed TyphoonConfigPostProcessor to explicitly use `[NSBundle mainBundle]` for the `id<TyphoonResource>`, and left the behavior of the `+(id<TyphoonResource>)withName:` method unchanged for now. This should also fix the problem. I pushed this as Typhoon 3.0.2. Works for you?

Comment: Yes it appears to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Typhoon 3.0.1. As you indicated when Typhoon is linked as a Swift framework the wrong bundle for TyphoonConfig resources is used. This has since been corrected in Typhoon 3.0.2.